# overpass-api: regex on keys

Tags: overpass-api

According to http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL
queries can use regular expressions on both the values and the keys.  While I have no trouble using regex on the values, I'm having a problem with the keys.

The example on the wiki referenced above says (among other examples):

```
/* finds addr:* tags with value exactly "Foo" */
node[~"^addr:.*$"~"^Foo$"];
```

So, that's an example of using regex on the keys and the values.

What I am interested in is the `name` key.  Specifically the `name:en` key.  There are a couple problems with searching by name.  Not all names are in English, and for those nodes/way/relations whose names are not in English, there is no guarantee there will be a `name:en` tag with an English version of the name.

In general, there is no way to know in advance if the name will be in English or that there is a `name:en` tag.  If you only ask for `name` or `name:en`, you run the risk of finding no hit.  (Of course, searching for both is no guarantee of success, either.)

I have a case where I know `name` fails, but `name:en` succeeds.  That is my test case.  I can query the overpass-api.de/api/interpreter using this:

```
[out:json][timeout:25][bbox:33.465530,36.156006,33.608615,36.574516];

(
  node[name~"duma",i][place];
  way[name~"duma",i][place];
  >;
  relation[name~"duma",i][place];
  node["name:en"~"duma",i][place];
  way["name:en"~"duma",i][place];
  >;relation["name:en"~"duma",i][place];
);

out center;
```

[see it on overpass](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25][bbox:33.465530,36.156006,33.608615,36.574516];(node[name~%22duma%22,i][place];way[name~%22duma%22,i][place];%3E;relation[name~%22duma%22,i][place];node[%22name:en%22~%22duma%22,i][place];way[%22name:en%22~%22duma%22,i][place];%3E;relation[%22name:en%22~%22duma%22,i][place];);out%20center;)
and it works fine ("duma" is not found through `name`, but it is found with `name:en`), but I find it lengthy and somewhat repetitive.

I would like to use a regular expression involving the `name` and `name:en` tags, but either the server does not understand the query or I simply am using an incorrect regex.

Using the example shown in the wiki: `node[~"^addr:.*$"~"^Foo$"]`
I have tried:

```
[~"name|name:en"~"duma",i]  
[~"name.*"~"duma",i]  
[~"^name.*$"~"duma",i]
```

and several others.  I even mimicked the example with `[~"^name:.*"~"duma",i]` just to see if anything would be returned.

Does overpass-api.de recognize regular expressions on the keys or do I just have the regex wrong?  I don't get an error from overpass-api.de, just the coordinates of the bbox and an empty result.  It's usually very strict about reacting to a poortly formatted query.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really a bug in the Overpass API implementation concerning case-insensitive key regex matching, see [this Github ticket](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/182) for details.

For the time being, you can already test the patch on the development box:

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/b1l

BTW: If you **don't** need case-insensitive regexp matching, this should already work on overpass-api.de as of today.

Comment: is it ok/possible to substitute 'http://dev.overpass-api.de/api_mmd/' for 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?' until the regex patch goes live?
  
my project involves an input box for the user's query and then a command line call to the server for json.  normally i 
wouldn't trouble overpass for geocoding.  (nominatim through mapquest does very well and handles case-insensitivity).  but if nominatim fails, the only option is overpass.  i'd like to incorporate the patch into my project, if ok.  -go

Comment: It might take several weeks, if not months until the patch might be picked up (there are some other large scale changes waiting to be merged first). In general, the dev instance is meant for testing, giving feedback on patches. Any kind of productive use is discouraged: the service might be unavailable at any time without prior notice, the URL might permanently change, etc.. Bottom line: there are no guarantees whatsoever regarding the dev box.

Comment: no problem. thanks for the follow up and for the initial clarification.  my 2-step query for "name" and later for "name:en" works fine.  case-insensitivity, i think, is pretty much required for use by general public, so i'll limp along until the patch grinds it way up the chain.  -go

Comment: ok, then. If this answers your question, please don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, nothing that i see on this page showing me how to accept the answer.  maybe there's a moderator to assist??  in any case, the question has been answered (again, with thanks) and maximum stars, if that's the practice on this forum.  -go

Comment: ok, no problem :) here's a link to it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - you simply have to click on the check mark next to the question, that's it.

Comment: i clicked on the check mark.  nothing seems to happen.  i don't get it, i'm sorry.  i've never seen such a busy, confusing page.  i am very sorry  -go